# After 15.10 update, I can't play Minecraft or FTB

Tags: xubuntu, java, launcher, firewall, minecraft

I have been able to play Minecraft fine earlier, with Xubuntu 15.4. Yesterday when I updated to 15.10 I am unable to play online. Here is the [launch log](http://pastebin.com/ZhbPgxfY). I have tried reinstalling both Minecraft itself and Java. I seem to have another problem with Feed the Beast (a modpack client for Minecraft) that gives me these errors:

```
Authlib checksum download failed, please check log for bad SSL 
certificates: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
find valid certification path to requested target
```

Here is another error from the FTB launcher:

```
SSL handshake failed. Something might be altering SSL certificates
Certificates are not trusted by JVM certificate chain
Certificate chain will be printed in debug logging level
Authlib Download Failed
```

And another one:

```
No usable authlib available. Please check your firewall rules and network 
connection. Can't start MC without working authlib. Launch button will be 
disabled.
```

For the record; I am not using a firewall and I have `chmod +x` every .jar file. I have searched around on several Minecraft and FTB forums for answers, but I havn't found any.

I think there is a possibility that these problems are related, but someone that knows more than me can probably prove me wrong.

I'd appreciate any help given.

Thanks!

EDIT: After a week with no responses I've almost given up. I still can't figure out what to do.

EDIT: I've removed `oracle-java` and replaced it with `open-jdk-8`. Now I get this error: `Recognized exception: the likely cause is a set of broken/missing root-certificates. Check your java install and perhaps reinstall it.`

```
Unable to download remote file. Check your internet connection/proxy settings.
FATAL ERROR: net.minecraft.bootstrap.FatalBootstrapError: Unable to download while being forced
    at net.minecraft.bootstrap.Bootstrap.execute(Bootstrap.java:95)
    at net.minecraft.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:381)


Please fix the error and restart.
```

I have messed around a bit and added a certificate to the `jre/lib/security/cacerts` file. With this I made some progress, now the log looks like this:

```
[20:58:32 INFO]: Logging in with username & password
[20:58:32 ERROR]: Couldn't log in
com.mojang.authlib.exceptions.AuthenticationUnavailableException: Cannot contact authentication server
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilAuthenticationService.makeRequest(YggdrasilAuthenticationService.java:71) ~[launcher.jar:1.6.44]
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilUserAuthentication.logInWithPassword(YggdrasilUserAuthentication.java:74) ~[launcher.jar:1.6.44]
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilUserAuthentication.logIn(YggdrasilUserAuthentication.java:57) ~[launcher.jar:1.6.44]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.ui.popups.login.LogInForm$4.run(LogInForm.java:171) [launcher.jar:1.6.44]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_66-internal]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1283) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1258) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at com.mojang.authlib.HttpAuthenticationService.performPostRequest(HttpAuthenticationService.java:73) ~[launcher.jar:1.6.44]
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilAuthenticationService.makeRequest(YggdrasilAuthenticationService.java:54) ~[launcher.jar:1.6.44]
    ... 6 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1283) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1258) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at com.mojang.authlib.HttpAuthenticationService.performPostRequest(HttpAuthenticationService.java:73) ~[launcher.jar:1.6.44]
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilAuthenticationService.makeRequest(YggdrasilAuthenticationService.java:54) ~[launcher.jar:1.6.44]
    ... 6 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1283) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1258) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250) ~[?:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at com.mojang.authlib.HttpAuthenticationService.performPostRequest(HttpAuthenticationService.java:73) ~[launcher.jar:1.6.44]
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilAuthenticationService.makeRequest(YggdrasilAuthenticationService.java:54) ~[launcher.jar:1.6.44]
    ... 6 more
```

To me this still looks like a problem with the certificates, but to be honest I don't know very much about things like this. Thanks for any eventual help. I'm still lost here. Does anyone have *any* idea of where to start?

Ok, now I've got some help, but I can't seem to figure out how to this anyway.
I have tested follow versions of Java:

- Oracle Java 8
- OpenJRE 8
- Oracle Java 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing and working with the awesome people in the FTB IRC, we got it to work. We changed a few things around (like linking cacerts into java's binary), but what actually fixed it was this command. Here you go :)

```
sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now! Many thanks to you and the FTB community!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to actually install java the right way at the first time, I have issues on the main machine I was trying to use even after this partly, what happened was I wrote a wrong command and everything got messed up.I tried to remove the package ca-certificates and it brought down half of Ubuntu... a clean re-installation with hours of reconfiguration was the result, so I can't recreate the issue anymore. 
To the solution now : 
 I suggest you remove every java installation and clean the folder for java manually as well. Now you could install a package called default-jre and that should do the trick. 
What it does is that it installs a package called ca-cetficates-java

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre

    The following extra packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java default-jre-headless fonts-dejavu-extra java-common libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libgif4 libgnomevfs2-0       libgnomevfs2-common libsctp1 lksctp-tools openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless tzdata-java
```

it will then bring the certificates needed for minecraft to work! it is as simple as that.

OLD:I have the same issue, it needs still more certificates but the latest error log doesn't say what site it tries to reach. a solution would be to make java accept any certificate. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828775/how-to-handle-invalid-ssl-certificates-with-apache-httpclient

Comment: Thank you! But I don't quite understand how to do it, even with the link you posted..

Comment: I have updated my answer, I hope it helps you, it seems it was much easier than what we expected after all.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking your time to help me, but sadly, this still didn't work. I still have the same error. I might just have to reinstall my whole system. :|

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem, but sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh didn't fix it. Turns out my version of icedtea was outdated relative to my verion of nss.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thank you for your input. However, what you have added is nore of a comment then an answer. Next time, please add text like this in as a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 0):

I could solve that error by using openjdk-8 instead of openjdk-11. To find out which version of java you use, type `java --version` in your terminal. By default, openjdk-java is installed at `/usr/lib/jvm/java-$version-openjdk-$platform` (where $version is the version e.g. 8 and $platform is the platform e.g. amd64). Should you find version 8 there, you can run the launcher with `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -jar FTB_launcher.jar`